# Coordinates Upload and CRS conversion

Tags: r, coordinates, data-conversion

I'm pretty new to working in R and I'm currently struggling on converting lat/long coordinates I uploaded into R from an xlsx document into the CRS of the raster I want to plot my coordinates on. I'm using RStudio Version 1.2.5033. Instead of linking the coordinates file, here are the lat/long coordinates I have uploaded (lat first then long):
1 Allequash (46.03323 -89.60874)
2 Bassett   (44.99034 -93.27385)
3 Chippewa  (44.93223 -91.38599)
4 Como      (45.10457 -91.53066)
5 Flambeau  (45.41387 -91.21639)
6 Minnehaha   (44.918 -93.22536)
7 Red Cedar (44.88263 -91.93599)
8 Shingle   (45.03322 -93.28645)
9 Trout     (45.09951 -91.65159)

I'll post my code first and then go into what problems I'm running into

```
site_coordinates<-read_excel(coordinates,sheet=1) #Proj=longlat datum=WGS84
rm(coordinates)
site_coordinates_crs<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

coordinates<-st_as_sf(site_coordinates,coords=c("Latitude","Longitude"),crs=site_coordinates_crs)
st_crs(coordinates)
coordinates_aes<-st_transform(coordinates,crs(nlcd)) 
# nlcd is the raster I'm plotting the coordinates on top of, uploaded online nlcd 2016 land use raster
```

The problems I'm running into:
1. When I check my coordinates after uploading them and then assigning them the crs using st_as_sf, I get the following warning message and I'm not sure why: 
In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data

2. When I then go to transform my coordinate data to match that of the raster using st_transform, I then only get the first site converted (Allequash, and even this conversion doesn't seem correct) while the other site coordinates remain empty.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The coords format is `coords = c("x", "y")`so just reverse your lat and long coordinates and it should work.